# What are the dangers of using Hibernate Search with Elasticsearch version alpha 3 in production?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am developing a e commerce application.I am using Spring MVC 4 annotation based configuration with hibernate and MySQL.I needed to integrate a search engine so I decide to go go with hibernate elastic search.**I need to know whether using Hibernate search alpha 3  in production environment will pose any threats to my eCommerce web application? If alpha version  is a threat then What can be a alternative solution for me?**

Comment: Well if hibernate fellows declared it alpha quality it just means it is... alpha quality. It can still contains hidden bugs. It is up to you to use it in production, but I would'nt dare...

Comment: Agreed, you should never use [alpha and beta versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Stages_of_development) into production, it is very risky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering on behalf of the Hibernate Search team (I'm the project lead).

When we release anything, it is *in our opinion* good code and we think that the features which we implemented to be reliable. You might think of it as being similar to when you code anything for your own project and consider something "done, this will do the job nicely".

But while we take pride in our goal to write great code, we're human and sometimes we're wrong.

We're testing in various environments and OS combinations, and any pull request is peer-reviewed by another committer, and open for scrutiny from anybody (it's all [public on github](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/pulls)) so I would say that the quality is generally quite high.

### What's the risk of using any non-Final version?

**Environment**

While we test in many combinations of OS, JDKs, databases, hardware types (small embedded to very high end servers), the combinations we can test are limited: Red Hat kindly sponsors us but the budget is not unlimited.

When you all download an Alpha/Beta and test it on your environment, you might catch some corner case that we don't know about. 
Do yourself a favour, and get your team to test regularly our preview builds on the environment which matters to you: if it fails and you can report it, we'll make sure that works for the Final release.

Several people help out by doing this, so the Final will have had much better coverage. However consider testing this in your own environment, so that your specific requirements are covered.

So when you push an Alpha in production, it might still have issues related to some environment that we don't know of yet. You could look into our issue tracker though, to see if any issues which other volunteers reported could bother you: if no issues are reported, changes are that the next release will not be "more reliable" than the Alpha but just the same again.

**Test Coverage**

We develop various unit tests and integration tests, and performance tests to cover new features and to be safe against regressions.

Other people might try to use the new features in ways that we didn't anticipate, or simply on field and type combinations which we didn't cover with your tests.

When you download our previews, and use it to resolve **your requirement**, that might uncover issues which we have not covered. The best way to make sure that the Final release will be suited for your requirements, is to try it out early on, and let us know what is not good yet.

If you send us a patch which adds a unit test to cover for your use case you can get a very high return on the investment: we'll include that test in our codebase, so that continuous integration will ensure that your requirements will be covered by future releases as well.

Of course if you tried and it works just fine - as we expect - then you might as well put it into production, as long as you understand the following points on what differentiates an Alpha from a Final.

### So what is different between an Alpha and a Beta release?

Generally it's about feature coverage.

For a Beta release we typically require it to be "feature complete": to have all the things implemented which we *think* you will need to benefit from the new features.

An example in this case could be that the Alpha release of 5.6 - the first version supporting Elasticsearch - didn't have the feature to rebuild the Index. I think having this option is essential for various practical reasons, but if your specific use case doesn't require it (you might have your own strategy?) then the lack of such a feature might not bother you.

A Beta release will incorporate any fixes about issues that you all have let us know from testing the Alpha version. So the chances that it will "just work" on your environment are even higher.

### What's different between a Beta and a Candidate Release or Final?

After [publishing the Beta1 release](http://in.relation.to/2016/05/24/ElasticsearchintegrationReachesBeta1/) we might still have some pending work to do, but we expect the API of new features to not change anymore. Unless someone has a significant and reasonable concern.

So we expect even more people to be happy to test a Beta, and when we received enough feedback like "It's working great!" (we love to hear that, please let us know!) then we make a call that enough people have tested it and we call it a Final release - possibly with a candidate release to give people a last chance to try it.

At this point it's probably too late to tell us that some API is confusing, that you'd suggest a method to be named differently, etc.. so make sure to try it out as early as practical for your project.

I hope that helps making a sensible choice for your specific use case.

In terms of *Ready for Production*: I think an Alpha is as ready as writing your own integration would be; just make sure you test it as you would your own team's code and study the release notes in detail to be equally aware of known limitations.

Much depends on how you can handle a potential issue with it: I would not recommend it on a mission critical system but there are people who ultimately get a better integration, because they can test early versions in an environment very similar to production, or they can handle the risk of having it production already.